# How to import mixpanel to Angular 2 + CLI project

Tags: angular, mixpanel

I'm using Angular 2+ and Angular CLI.

How do I add Mixpanel to my project?

Comment: Genuinely curious why this is being down-voted. Is it not a legitimate question or am I already supposed to know this?

Comment: it is a legitimate one. like you I am a bit surprised of the reaction of some people that spend their time to propose a suggested edit of a reply to a question ... sorry if this is off-topic ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title should be 'How to use Third party/vendor library with angular2'

Suppose the api script is mixpanel.js
modifiy src/app/vendors.ts to import it :

```
import 'mixpanel';
```

then your ts file :

```
import * from 'mixpanel' as mixpanel;
```

then use it using func calls like this :

```
mixpanel.function1() ...
```

or You can use a wrapper like angulartics2 :  https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2